# Get maximum available heap memory

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently trying to figure out the maximum memory that is able to be allocated through the malloc() command in C. 
Until now I´ve tried a simple algorithm that increments a counter that will subsequently be allocated. If the malloc command returns "NULL" I know, that there is not enough memory available.

```
        ULONG ulMaxSize = 0;

        for (ULONG ulSize = /*0x40036FF0*/ 0x40A00000; ulSize <= 0xffffffff; ulSize++)
        {
            void* pBuffer = malloc(ulSize);
            if (pBuffer == NULL)
            {
                ulMaxSize = ulSize - 1;
                break;
            }
            free(pBuffer);
        }

        void* pMaxBuffer = malloc(ulMaxSize);
```

However, this algorithm gets executed very long since the malloc() command has turned out to be a time consuming task.

My question is now, if there is a more efficient algorithm to find the maximum memory able to be allocated?

Comment: depending on the operating system this might cause your process to be killed, or trigger an OOM manager. Although again depending on your OS you might already have API for getting such number

Comment: For linux you can get a look at [sysinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html)

Comment: So what is the respective API for a Windows platform?

Comment: win32 equivalent would be [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex)

Comment: Note that Linux, in it's default configuration with memory overcommit enabled, will *de facto* lie to your program about how much memory is available.  If your process dares to actually use the memory asked for, your process will likely be killed by the [out-of-fuel, errr, out-of-memory killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/). (Hopefully, no critical process will be [whacked](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whacked) as collateral damage...) So there's no real way to get the maximum memory able to be allocated on a default Linux installation.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum memory that can be allocated depends mostly on few factors:

- Address space limits on the process (max memory, virtual memory and friends).
- Virtual space available
- Physical space available
- Fragmentation, which will limit the size of continuous memory blocks.
- ... Other limits ...

From your description (extreme slowness) looks like the process start using swap, which is VERY slow vs. real memory.

Consider the following alternative

- For address space limit, look at `ulimit -a` (or use getrlimit to access the same data from C program) - look for 'max memory size', and 'virtual memory'
- For swap space, physical memory - top

```
ulimit -a (filtered)

data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 2048
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

From a practical point, given that a program does not have control over system resources, you should be focused on 'max memory size'.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using OS specific API to get such number :

- [`sysinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html) on linux or reading it from `/proc/meminfo` )
- [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-globalmemorystatusex) for win32

You can also do a binary search, not recommended, as the state of the system might be in flux and the result could vary over time:

```
ULONG getMax() {
    ULONG min = 0x0;
    ULONG max = 0xffffffff;
    void* t = malloc(max);
    if(t!=NULL) {
        free(t);
        return max;
    }
    while(max-min > 1) {
        ULONG mid = min + (max - min) / 2;
        t = malloc(mid);
        if(t == NULL) {
            max = mid;
            continue;
        }
        free(t);
        min = mid;
    }
    return min;
}
```